# How to treat numbers inside text strings when vectorizing words?

Tags: tensorflow, nlp, word2vec, word-embedding

If I have a text string to be vectorized, how should I handle numbers inside it? Or if I feed a Neural Network with numbers and words, how can I keep the numbers as numbers?

I am planning on making a dictionary of all my words ([as suggested here](https://github.com/tflearn/tflearn/issues/124#issuecomment-223478145)). In this case all strings will become arrays of numbers. How should I handle characters that are numbers? how to output a vector that does not mix the word index with the number character?

Does converting numbers to strings weakens the information i feed the network?

Comment: In many applications words that don't exist in the dictionary, are converted as to `<unknown>`. In the same way, depending on your application, it could be convenient to convert all the numbers to a special token, like `<number>`.

Answer (score 6):

Expanding your discussion with @user1735003 - Lets consider both ways of representing numbers:

1. Treating it as string and considering it as another word and assign an ID to it when forming a dictionary. Or
2. Converting the numbers to actual words : '1' becomes 'one', '2' as 'two' and so on.

Does the second one change the context in anyway?. To verify it we can find similarity of two representations using [`word2vec`](http://bionlp-www.utu.fi/wv_demo/). The scores will be high if they have similar context.

For example, 
      `1` and `one` have a similarity score of 0.17, `2` and `two` have a similarity score of `0.23`. They seem to suggest that the context of how they are used is totally different.

> By treating the numbers as another word, you are not changing the
>   context but by doing any other transformation on those numbers, you
>   can't guarantee its for better. So, its better to leave it untouched and treat it as another word.

***Note***: Both `word-2-vec` and `glove` were trained by treating the numbers as strings (case 1).

Answer (score 2):

The link you provide suggests that everything resulting from a `.split(' ')` is indexed -- words, but also numbers, possibly smileys, aso. (*I would still take care of punctuation marks*). Unless you have more prior knowledge about your data or your problem you could start with that.

**EDIT**

Example literally using your string and their code:

```
corpus = {'my car number 3'}
dictionary = {}
i = 1
for tweet in corpus:
  for word in tweet.split(" "):
    if word not in dictionary: dictionary[word] = i
    i += 1
print(dictionary)
# {'my': 1, '3': 4, 'car': 2, 'number': 3}
```

Comment: But imagine I have a word "car" that gets the index `3` in my dictionary. If I also have the number `3` in the text (in a phrase like `The car number 3`) it makes no sense to feed the network a vector with false repeated  numbers like [12, **3**, 11, **3**] which could be interpreted like `The car number car`.

Comment: You don't have the number `3`, you have the *string* `"3"`, which may be indexed by any number.

Comment: But that removes from the input the _Type_, being a number is information itself.

Comment: Not really. `"3"` is a string. What it means depend on the context. It could be a number -- maybe. So is `"three"` -- a good old alphabetical string, mind you. It could be some sort of ID, in which case it should probably not be considered as a number. The idea of ML is letting the computer grasp the meaning itself from the context, without resorting to hand-made rules.

Comment: More pragmatically, if you reserve id `n` to represent string `"n"`, for all numbers `n`, you don't get to have any id left for other strings.

Answer (score 1):

The following paper can be helpful: http://people.csail.mit.edu/mcollins/6864/slides/bikel.pdf

Specifically, page 7.

Before they use an `<unknown>` tag they try to replace alphanumeric symbol combination with common pattern names tags, such as:

```
FourDigits (good for years)
```

I've tried to implement it and it gave great results.